# Why Cannot I login to my FTP Server?

Tags: networking, ftp, iis

I am creating an FTP server using IIS to store some files.

**Here's what I did:**

1. I turned on the IIS feature and subfeatures in Control Panel -> Programs and Features.
2. From the IIS Manager, I created a new FTP site under the Sites section.
3. I entered my site name, and the folder is in my C:\ drive.
4. My IP Address came from the ipv4 address that I obtained from the command ipconfig. Port is 21, and no SSL.
5. I allowed anonymous and basic authentication, with read and write allowed.

My firewall was turned off during the process.

**Now, here's what went wrong:**
I typed in the ftp address (ftp://) into my file explorer, and I got this error:

"either the server does not allow anonymous logins or email not accepted".

I logged in with my account name machineName/myName, and the password for my account, and I still cannot log in. In fact, my account is bind with a Microsoft account.

May I know how I can fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a bad idea to share your C:\ drive. Without firewall and with anonymous login enabled even more so!!

Try a different directory and make sure the access rights are set correctly.

Maybe it could help to create a user specifically to access this FTP share. This user can be provided with the appropriate rights more easily.